# c# project dont copy some DLL's in Bin/Debug

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am working on VS2012
I have a project A referencing a project B that refers to other DLLs (C1, C2, C3 for instance).
I have a Unit Test project for A (A.test) referencing A and the same project B.

In the Bin\Debug of A, I have B.dll, C1.dll ,C2.dll ,C3.dll. (all is well)
In the Bin\Debug of A.test, I have B.dll, C1.dll ,C3.dll but no C2.dll

I have all-ready checked :

- the .net framework version between all the projects.
- the references between the projects.
- compared the csproj files
- searched a solution on stack overflow.
- Copy Local set to true

Does somebody have an idea please ?

At run time, the unit test goes on error with a System.IO.FileNotFoundException for C2.Dll

**Edit :** Precision, C2.DLL is not directly used. I use objects from C1.dll and C1 needs C2 to work.

**Edit 2** It is certainly a problem with the way that C1 refers to C2. If no object from C2 is used in B, there is no copy of C2.Dll. If I had some code that refers to C2 in B, C2.Dll is copied. So I had to add C2.dll in A.Test. It's not a very good solution but it works, so...

Comment: Can you tell what exactly the problem is?

Comment: did you specify the flag "copy local" on the referred dll?

Comment: @DominicTrade He said the C2.dll is not getting copied correctly, read the question before you downvote

Comment: @Bauhaus Ah, did not see that. It was not btw me, that downvoted, really not. War wirklich nicht ich.

Comment: A.test references A (to test it) and B in order to mock some methods.

Comment: I know you've said you have checked the references, but could you double check the references in A.test are all project references and not file references.

Comment: @Bauhaus ahh sorry about that, the downvote occurred at the exact same time as your comment, bad assumption

Comment: @Psych : I have checked this, no change.